# Has anyone tried to package omnichannel as part of an unlocked package?

Tags: liveagent, unlocked-package, omnichannel, einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots

I am deploying an Einstein Bot that uses omnichannel for routing. I am having a hard time deploying a LiveChatButton using omnichannel routing b.c it does not add the routing type in the metadata file.
I see there is a workaround option by changing it to ‘skill’ based while deploying and updating it in Salesforce after deployment.
I am trying to package all of this in an unlocked package and deploy the LiveChatButton within the package

Has anyone deployed omnichannel metadata or packaged it?

Comment: Take a look at the [metadata coverage report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/60) where you will probably find you cannot...

Comment: Yea, looks like I cannot add it to the package, but I am wondering how people are deploying this.